# Custom risers for bed without legs

Tags: technique, wood, furniture

My bed sits on a frame, so there are no legs to put off the shelf raisers , I am thinking of cutting a lap on 4x4 to the width of bed frame and fastened it with two bolts, for good support I am hoping 4 on corners and one on each side in middle of frame

My question is this feasible approach and will it provide sufficient structural support?

Comment: So do I understand correctly, are you basically adding six feet to the bed frame made from pieces of 4x4? If so I would say so plainly so that people aren't struggling to visualise the plan. Even a quick sketch would help here. You should also mention the material the frame is made from (I'm assuming steel) and how thick it is. Bed dimensions would also be useful.

Comment: I'm hesitating to edit this, but my gut tells me that the term you want is "riser" not "raiser"...

Comment: @graphus Thanks guys, Will probably make a riser and post the picture